# Xamarin android error : E:/work/Xamarin/Test/App3/App3/obj/Debug/resourcecache/AAE07979B017EA1E6B70B

Tags: android, xamarin, aapt

```
Vs 2015 xamarin android project;
 Build error message => E:/work/Xamarin/Test/App3/App3/obj/Debug/resourcecache/AAE07979B017EA1E6B70BA4C7E4A3319/res' does not exist App3 E:/work/Xamarin/Test/App3/App3/AAPT
```

I am just about to give up Xamarin now.

The same project is not a problem on other PCs;

I even tried reinstalling visualstudio and xamarin.

Comment: Could you please share the complete build log? It will help us to troubleshoot the issue. You can refer this link to the build logs - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/version-logs/#verbose-build-output-logs

Comment: I write my current state, my dev pc does format hdd 3 days ago. and reinstall visual studio. so fine from build error. now important thing, I forget the xamarin in visual studio. I will using android studio. say me, if your xamarin is complete then say me "reusing our xamarin in visual studio". I like c# project and c++ project and mfc project yet. hu hu xamarin c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

-Right click on your solution, select the "Batch Build..." option.

-Click in Select All, and Clean.

-Now, repeat the first step, select all and Build.

--(Check if the error will still happening.)--

Answer (score 0):

Got exactly same problem. Please try delete everything in

> "C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Xamarin\"

Then clean rebuild. It may take a long time to recreate everything in that folder, and then it should work.